# Refactoring Code in Unity by not using the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a portal in my unity game. By entering the trigger it should load a scene. So this code is really short, here it is:

```
public class PortalData : EnvironmentCommonData // the data class with some information
{
    public PortalData(string sceneToLoad) // set the scene in the constructor
    {
        SceneToLoad = sceneToLoad;
    }

    public string SceneToLoad { get; set; } // the scene to load when entering
}

public class PortalController : EnvironmentCommonController // the portal class
{
    [SerializeField]
    string sceneToLoad; // set the scene in the inspector

    private PortalData data;

    private void Start()
    {
        data = new PortalData(sceneToLoad); // instance for the data class
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) // player enters the trigger
    {
        if (CheckCollision(col, data.PlayerObject)) // is the entering object the player?
            LoadScene(data.SceneToLoad); // load the new scene
    }
}
```

So I am looking for a smart way not to use the inspector. I want to have it all automated by scripts.

So I tried to set the controller abstract and created different controller classes inheriting from this controller but that's not elegant.

Here you could see an example of my try:

https://hastebin.com/utuqubafuz.cs

Does someone got an idea?

Well the perfect script would look like this

```
public class Portal : Monobehaviour
{
    string sceneToLoad = "";

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
    }
}
```

but I don't want the inspector, if possible.

Comment: You'd have to be creating them somewhere. If you have them spawned in the scene already, just use the Inspector. If you're creating them with code, *that's* where you'd specify the string instead.

Comment: You want to generate the value of `sceneToLoad` variable from run-time? If so, what are the names of your scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have `PortalSpawner` to Instantiate `GameObject`s, attach `Portal` objects to them  via `AddComponent()`, and set `string newPortal.sceneToLoad`. While this may avoid setting strings with the Inspector, it still requires you to specify the string somewhere, as @Draco18s mentioned in the comment.

Other ways would be:

1. subclasses for each scene that have specifically declared the `string sceneToLoad`,
2. reusing Prefabs for the same scene in different locations,
3. if it's writing `string` that you want to avoid, you could use `enum` and check for each enum values and load scene accrodingly (code will look dirtier but might make Inspector cleaner), OR
4. make a JSON file (or any other database or serialisable texts) where you store the positions of `Portal` Objects to spawn, which `string newPortal.sceneToLoad` each of them should contain. Ultimately this will go back to the `AddComponent()` approach.

The JSON approach may be closer to what you are looking for, but it requires some more work and I'm not sure if it's worth the efforts.

If these are not solutions you are looking for, please provide at which steps you want automation to happen. The `sceneToLoad` must be specified at a certain point anyways. The Inspector fields are the common place to do this in Unity I believe.

As a side, sticking to scene naming convention might make some of the process easier. So for example, scene names must be `sceneNumber_k` where `k` is the scene's index, and the kth `Portal` will open kth scene. With this kind of naming conventions some of the process in initialising the strings may be *automated*.